# retrofit not valid URI

Tags: java, retrofit

Hi I'm trying to do a simple http get query via `Retrofit`.

My parameter has some special characters and it seems that the url encoding fails.

Original:

```
data=[out:json];node["name"~"Karlsruhe"]["place"~"city|village|town"];out body;
```

correct encoding should look like this:

```
data=%5Bout%3Ajson%5D%3Bnode%5B%22name%22~%22Karlsruhe%22%5D%5B%22place%22~%22city%7Cvillage%7Ctown%22%5D%3Bout%20body%3B
```

but Retrofit creates this:

```
data=[out:json];node[%22name%22~%22Karlsruhe%22][%22place%22~%22city|village|town%22];out%20body;
```

and this will fail with:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: not valid as a java.net.URI:
>   http://overpass.osm.rambler.ru/cgi/interpreter?data=[out:json];node[%22name%22~%22Karlsruhe%22][%22place%22~%22city|village|town%22];out%20body;
>     at com.squareup.okhttp.HttpUrl.uri(HttpUrl.java:336)    at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextProxy(RouteSelector.java:135)
>     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.(RouteSelector.java:71)
>     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.get(RouteSelector.java:76)
>     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:321)
>     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:245)
>     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:267)  at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:224)
>     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:195)
>     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)   at
>   retrofit.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:112)

What can be done here to fix this encoding issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure about what the root cause of the encoding error is, but you can work around it with the `encoded` parameter to the [`Query`](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/http/Query.html) notation.  Setting the parameter to `true` tells retrofit the parameter is already encoded, so do not encode again.

In your service interface, add `encoded=true` to your `@Query` annotation.  Something like --

```
Call<ResponseBody> getResponse(@Query(value = "data", encoded = true) String data);
```

Then, encode the parameter yourself before sending to retrofit.

```
final String encodedData = URLEncoder.encode(data, "UTF-8");
Call<ResponseBody> result = service.getResponse(encodedData);
```

Comment: This will be fixed in OkHttp 2.6.0-SNAPSHOT.